# How to force Cortana OAuth not to use Magic Code

Tags: javascript, botframework, cortana, cortana-skills-kit

I used the [botbuilder-js](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-js) to write a custom bot. At some point it requires the user to sign in, so the bot sends out the `OAuthPrompt` dialog, which makes user sign in (with google, which I have configured in Azure Portal OAuth Connection Settings). It works fine in the Bot Framework Emulator, but when I integrate the bot with Cortana, after the user signs in, he lands on this page:

[image]

The fun part is that this dialog is modal, so I cannot paste the code in the Cortana chat even if I wanted to.

What do I need to do to force Cortana to not require this magic code?

Comment: Did you turn on "Connected Services"?  Don't.  If you are using bot service sign in cards or auth, you are responsible for the oauth flow.  Cortana only support transparent handling of oauth if you delegate to it (that is, you set up the cortana channel oauth via its config page.)  And then, the login portion is owned by the identity management provider (so... it looks like your redirect url is bad; what is it?)

Comment: No, I didn't configure Connected services within Cortana setup - I use "OAuth Connection Settings" which are in bot settings.
I added a "Google" service provider (which my bot references), set my Client Id + Client Secret + Scope ("email"). So I didn't put in a redirect url anywhere

Comment: Cortana is dumb when it puts up a canvas for an oauth or sign in card. It defers to the identity manager (in your case google) to render a decent experience. Looks like the 2FA set up on the account mangles the experience.  I can try replicate it, but I likely can't do anything about it. Perhaps also ask the question of google oauth experts.

Comment: Please send me the exact oauth connection settings; I need to see the authorization URI and the redirect URI.  Feel free to scrub the client_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already answered this on the GitHub [botbuilder-js repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-js/issues/699). Answering for greater visibility.

It does appear to be a bug. I was able to repro the issue. If you copy the code down you can enter the code as a new command to the bot. It's a terrible work around, but it will work until the UI is fixed. Follow these steps:

1. Open Cortana and connect to your bot ("tell [bot] hi")
2. Click login option
3. Write down magic code from window
4. Open Cortana and re-connect to your bot

   - Tell your bot the magic code ("tell [bot] [magic code]")
   - Login should succeed
5. Interact with your bot

Answer (score 0):

Following the instructions on Google, I discovered that the redirect URL is why you are prompted for a magic code.  If you use Google tools, and you set up for out-of-band auth, you will get an OAuth authorization URL that looks like this...

```
Authorize this app by visiting this url: 
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive.metadata.readonly&response_type=code&client_id=[my client id]&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob
Enter the code from that page here: [your code]
```

You shouldn't set up for out of band auth (aka copy/paste auth `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`) - because it means that the identity manager is not calling the redirect_url (or redirect_uri) when the flow completes (letting bot service or cortana know that you're done signing in), and more important, you probably don't want the user to paste in some code to get the access token.  If you follow https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp you will see the redirect uri should be either bot frameworks, or cortanas, not out of band. Do this, and the code should get ingested programmaticly by the requestor.  You can configure this in the Google app reg clicking the credentials blade.

Comment: The redirect uri for bot service is `https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect` and the redirect uri for Cortana is `https://www.bing.com/agents/oauth`.  You can support both if your bot supports multiple channels (and differentiate behavior based on the channel name attached to the event) - just make sure to change Cortana's login prompt to "Sign in when required"